# File picker similar to one at google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, picker, google-sheets-api

I have an application running in servlet container, it is already integrated with google oauth2. Now I want to import google sheets into it using google sheets API. For that I need file picker where user can select the google sheet to be imported. I want exactly same file picker that is available on sheets.google.com. Is it possible to integrate it with custom application or I have to develop solution my self? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you something to start with. Try this Google Picker from [Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). It allows you to download and upload files using the Picker. [Code is located here](http://pastebin.com/wGdk95Pu). Check the Picker guide so you can modify it to your bidding.

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, can I also get tab to select google sheets shared with me?

Comment: I prefer you study the code and see how it works :) You might want to check about the MiMEtype for spreadsheets.